# Python ctypes dll call

Tags: python, ctypes

So I am basically new to python ctypes and I have little or no knowledge on C programming or any none python language...but I have a solid understanding of the `dll` protocol and working...so I made this call into a dll file to access a `printf` and then use it....my result came out oddly and not as expected....can anyone help explain what is happening here ...here's my code

```
From ctypes import *

msvcrt = cdll.msvcrt
message_string = "Hello World! \n"
msvcrt.printf("Testing: %s", message_string)
```

And here is my result

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you must pass a bytes string (b"whatever") not a regular python literal string.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6273618/3870025

```py
From ctypes import *
msvcrt = cdll.msvcrt
message_string = "Hello World! \n"
msvcrt.printf(b"Testing: %s", message_string)
```

Comment: You might have forgotten the `b` before the string to make it type byte.

Answer (score 0):

```html
from ctypes import *
msvcrt = cdll.msvcrt

message_string = b"Hello World!\n"
msvcrt.printf(b"Testing: %s", message_string)
```

Note that printf prints to the real standard output channel, not to sys.stdout, so these examples will only work at the console prompt, not from within IDLE or PythonWin: